# Cannot create instance of View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a  `UIView`subclass. I am not able to create an instance of another View Controller in this `UIView` class, so that i can access the variables set in my `UIView` subclass in this View Controller? Can anyone guide me on this

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "DirectoryFormViewController.h"
 @class NIDropDown;

 @protocol NIDropDownDelegate
 - (void) niDropDownDelegateMethod: (NIDropDown *) sender;
 @end

 @interface NIDropDown : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
 {
   NSString *animationDirection;
   UIImageView *imgView;
   DirectoryFormViewController *dict;  // i am not able to create this
 }



   @property (nonatomic, retain) id <NIDropDownDelegate> delegate;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *animationDirection;
   -(void)hideDropDown:(UIButton *)b;
    - (id)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSArray *)imgArr:       (NSString *)direction;
    @property(nonatomic)int countryID;
@end
```

My DirectoyFormViewController:

```
                #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

          #import "NIDropDown.h"
          @interface DirectoryFormViewController :   UIViewController<DropDownListDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,NIDropDownDelegate>


   @property(nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *countryName;
   @property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableDictionary *sortName;
   @property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableDictionary *resultName;


   @end
```

I want to set countryName,sortName and resultName in my NIDropDown

Thanks

Comment: what you have done? share your code

Comment: any error or warnings

Comment: Unknown Type name for `DirectoryFormViewController`

Comment: `UIView` as a table view delegate & datasource? Good luck with that.

Comment: @Desdenova NIDropDown is a library.

Comment: What's inside DirectoryFormViewController.h?

Comment: @PhillipMills i have set property in DirectoryFormViewController which i need to access in my NIDropDown.

Comment: Looking at what you are adding to this `UView` I would suggest to review your architecture as something really bad is going on behind the scene

Comment: Let me try that again....  What **code** is inside DirectoryFormViewController.h?

Comment: "@class DirectoryFormViewController"; write it after @class NIDropDown

Comment: @santhu i tried but getting error in my DirectoryFormViewController

Comment: Above `@interface DirectoryFormViewController ...` add `@class NIDopDown;`

Comment: I think there is a looping happening. you are importing, NIDropDown in DirectoryFormViewController.h at the same time you are importing DirectoryFormViewController in NIDropDown.h. Try importing NIDropDown in DirectoryFormViewController.m file not .h file.

Comment: did you try deleting `@class NIDropDown`? Why are you making a forward declaration a class to its self?

Comment: @santhu i am creating an instance of NIDropDown in my DirectoryFormViewController so i cannot import it in my DirectoryFormViewController.m

Comment: @Popeye the problem still persists

Comment: @anish: you can import it in DirectoryFormViewController.m file. Try it once.

Comment: @santhu tried already, it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Here's the short answer: you should **never, ever, not for any reason** create an instance of a view controller inside of a UIView. So the fact that you have not been successful so far is a good thing.

The Apple way of development on iOS is to use the [Model, View, Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) design pattern. In MVC, the controller controls the models and the views and mediates communication between the two... not the other way around.

My suggestion is that you read the link and fully understand it before moving forward with development. With an understanding of the topics covered you'll never do things like have a UIView that's a table view delegate / datasource (because by doing that, your view is aware of the model, and that breaks MVC), and you'll hopefully never try to do things like create a UIViewController in a UIView.